# Why does ng-show glitch when I build with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am currently using Ionic Framework as my javascript framework for my PhoneGap app.

I have an item on one of my pages that I want to be expandable and collapsible when I click an anchor on the page. Here is was that code looks like:

In my HTML:

```
<a ng-click="collapse(3)">Expand/Collapse test</a>

<a ng-show="children[3]">child</a>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.collapse = function(number) {
    if ( ($scope.showChild[number] = false) || ($scope.showChild[number] = null) )
        $scope.showChild[number] = true;
    else
        $scope.showChild[number] = false;
};
```

When I look at it through my mobile safari browser, it works as intended. In other words, when I click on the Expand/Collapse test anchor, the anchor with the text "child" in it shows and hides accordingly. The problem comes when I send it to adobe build and load it as an app on my phone. Once I do this, it works inconsistently (no matter how slow I press on the anchor.) It works if I scroll around the page before clicking on the "Expand/Collapse Test" anchor each time, but if I just keep the page static without scrolling, and click on the "Expand/Collapse test" anchor, it doesn't show or hide the "child" anchor until I click somewhere else on the screen.

Any ideas? I really don't want to implement jquery onclick listeners if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding the ngTouch module? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch  It overloads ng-click with enhancements for mobile browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @c0bra. This didn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue with Ionic Framework and asynchronous loading. I had to place a timeout on the button listener in order for this to work. The bug is being looked at by the dev team.

Source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/742